# Выполнение транзакций MySQL

Tags: mysql, транзакции

Почему при выполнении транзакции с запросом с ошибкой коммит всё равно срабатывает для запросов, выполненных успешно? Например, при попытке вставки записей в таблицу, где есть всего два поля `name` и `description`:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO ibareport.test (`name`, `description`) VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO ibareport.test (`name`, `description`) VALUES ('2', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO ibareport.test (`name`, `description`) VALUES ('3', '3');

COMMIT;
```

я получаю следующей результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём на выполнение запускались все запросы сразу, а не по одному. Почему в случае ошибки все запросы не откатываются, разве не в этом смысл транзакций?

И можно ли (и если да, то как?) выполнить транзакцию, чтобы в случае ошибки все запросы откатывались?

Comment: Подтвердите экспериментом в CLI. Вдруг ваш клиент не умеет транзакции. Или ещё банальнее: может, у вас вообще нетранзакционный движок у таблицы.

Comment: @Мелкий, движок точно транзакционный - InnoDB.

Comment: @Мелкий, да и клиент - SQLyog - вроде как должен поддерживать транзакции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ох и странно же у mysql транзакции сделаны. Ошибка одного запроса не рассматривается как необходимость отката транзакции, как, например, в postgresql.

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
mysql> insert into testtrans (`name`, `description`) VALUES ('1', '1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
mysql> insert into testtrans (`name`, `description`) VALUES ('1', '1');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql> insert into testtrans (`name`, `description`) VALUES ('2', '2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
```

В параллельном сеансе при этом

```
mysql> select * from testtrans;
Empty set (0,00 sec)
```

Т.е. мы всё-таки ещё в транзакции.

После `commit` в первом сеансе транзакция реально закоммитилась вместо более ожидаемого запрета на коммит и принудительного `rollback`. И затем данные появились и в другом сеансе.

Если mysql вернула ошибку на запрос - то это, оказывается, ваша обязанность увидеть ошибку и сказать rollback вместо commit. Сама субд вам позволит закоммитить эту транзакцию. Странный mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать следующий вид инсерта

```
INSERT INTO ibareport.test (`name`, `description`) VALUES ('1', '1'), ('1', '1'), ('1', '1');
```

В таком случае если одна из группы будет содержать больше значений чем столбцов в таблице, вся транзакция прервется.

Если считать что в таблицы нужно вставлять разные данные, и на момент вставки в таблицах уже есть какие то данные, то правильнее наверное будет примерно такое решение

```
DECLARE @ok as int = 0

create table #pre_data1 (id int, n int)
create table #pre_data2 (id int, n int)

create table #data1 (id int, n int)
create table #data2 (id int, n int)


BEGIN TRY
 insert into #pre_data1 (id,n) values (1,1),(2,2)
 insert into #pre_data1 (id,n) values (4,4),(5,5,5)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 set @ok = 1
END CATCH

IF @ok = 0 BEGIN
 insert into #data1
 select * from #pre_data1

 insert into #data2
 select * from #pre_data2
END
```

Т.е. мы пробуем засунуть данные в таблицы #pre_dataX, и если нам удается это сделать, а значит ошибок не было, то может перегонять эти данные в основные таблички #dataX. В противном же случае, в основные таблички ничего инсертиться не будет, а данные останутся во временных таблицах

Comment: Да, спасибо, но я хотела бы ещё понять, почему я получила результат, который был описан выше? И хотела бы понять, как работают транзакции... И этот запрос вообще является транзакцией?

Comment: Сделал небольшой пример, в моем случае все работает как и должно, т.е. если значений больше чем столбцов в таблице, запрос падает с ошибкой, при этом в таблице не записывается ничего. Думаю это какая то особенность MySQL (у вас же эта бд?), которая инсерт выполняет последовательно и на каждую своя транзакция.

Comment: Да, MySQL. Но как быть, если мне нужно выполнить вставку записей не в одну таблицу, а в несколько, и чтобы это прошло как одна транзакция? Тогда ваш пример вроде как не поможет...

Comment: Исправил ответ, может быть способ подойдет.

Comment: Как-то это слишком сложно... а с помощью транзакций всё-таки это реализовать не удастся?)

Comment: Не знаю, к сожалению с mysql не работал

Answer (score 0):

В случае SQL ошибки, транзакция сама по себе не откатится. Обычно ошибки обрабатываются уже с помощью sql wrapper’ов в самом приложении. Если вы захотите откатывать изменения в случае ошибки прямо в MySQL, можно создать специальную процедуру и уже в ней выполнять ROLLBACK в обработчике:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_test()
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK; //Вот здесь откатываем транзакцию в случае ошибки
  END;

END;
```